# Display transactions data with consecutive days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this `Transactions` table in Oracle 11G. Please, don't judge my asking question.

Table has columns:

```
id (guid type)
sender_name
transaction_date
amount
sender_address
sender_phone
receiver_name
```

Format of `transaction_date` column is like `2014-11-30 04:26:29.000000`.

What I want is: to display all data from `Transactions` table where those `sender_name` who sent more than 1000 `amount (sum(amount))` on 5 consecutive days in given `transaction_date between 01.01.2023 to 01.10.2023`.

Even if, for example `sender_name` sent money on April month 5 consecutive days and on June also have sent 5 consecutive days display all.

Could someone tell how to do this, please?

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (id, sender_name, transaction_date, amount) AS
SELECT '1111', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-26 01:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2222', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-27 02:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3333', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 03:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4444', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-29 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5555', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT '6666', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7777', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  
SELECT '9999', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-26 01:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8888', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-27 02:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 03:26:29',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4567', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 08:26:29',  501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2345', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-29 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3456', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5678', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  
SELECT '9999', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-26 01:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8888', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-27 02:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 03:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4567', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 08:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2345', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3456', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5678', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL;
```

The result I want  all datas of `Alice`-s rows. Because of total amount each they sent more than 10000 on 5 consecutive days. If I change 5 consecutive days to more than 5, than display `Carol`-s rows.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to show some extra effort.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; details of the issues/errors with **YOUR** query (i.e. the complete error message as text, not images); and the expected output for your sample data. Just stating "getting trouble with columns aliases" does not tell us what the trouble is and whether it is a problem with the IDE you are using or whether Oracle is returning an exception or whether it is something else.

Comment: @MT0 I edit the question and tried your code. Is that issue with IDE?

Comment: And tried also another IDE still same issue

Comment: As for your edit - you have not defined an alias on the in-line views and the table alias `"a"` is only relevant in the inner-most query where you have defined that alias (and stop using quoted identifiers when you do not need to). See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a4icc1um) from the comment on my question which shows how to add the aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can have multiple transactions occurring on a single day then you can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function over the days for each `sender_name` to find the groups of consecutive days. Then for each group you can find the start and end days and filter to only those rows where there are 5 or more days:

```sql
SELECT id,
       sender_name,
       transaction_date,
       amount
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         sender_name,
         transaction_date,
         amount,
         MAX(TRUNC(transaction_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY sender_name, grp)
         - MIN(TRUNC(transaction_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY sender_name, grp)
         + 1
           AS num_days
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           sender_name,
           transaction_date,
           amount,
           TRUNC(transaction_date)
           - DENSE_RANK() OVER (
               PARTITION BY sender_name ORDER BY TRUNC(transaction_date)
             ) AS grp
    FROM   (
      SELECT id,
             sender_name,
             transaction_date,
             amount,
             SUM(amount) OVER (
               PARTITION BY sender_name, TRUNC(transaction_date)
             ) AS daily_amount
      FROM   transactions
    )
    WHERE  daily_amount > 1000
  )
)
WHERE  num_days >= 5
ORDER BY sender_name, transaction_date;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transactions (id, sender_name, transaction_date, amount) AS
SELECT '1111', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-26 01:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2222', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-27 02:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3333', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 03:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4444', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-29 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5555', 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT '6666', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7777', 'Betty', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  
SELECT '9999', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-26 01:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8888', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-27 02:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 03:26:29',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4567', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 08:26:29',  501 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2345', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-29 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3456', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5678', 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  
SELECT '9999', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-26 01:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '8888', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-27 02:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 03:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4567', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-28 08:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2345', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 04:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3456', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-11-30 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5678', 'Debra', TIMESTAMP '2014-12-01 05:26:29', 1001 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | SENDER_NAME | TRANSACTION_DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Alice | 2014-11-26 01:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 2222 | Alice | 2014-11-27 02:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 3333 | Alice | 2014-11-28 03:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 4444 | Alice | 2014-11-29 04:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 5555 | Alice | 2014-11-30 05:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 9999 | Carol | 2014-11-26 01:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 8888 | Carol | 2014-11-27 02:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 1234 | Carol | 2014-11-28 03:26:29.000000000 | 500 |
| 4567 | Carol | 2014-11-28 08:26:29.000000000 | 501 |
| 2345 | Carol | 2014-11-29 04:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 3456 | Carol | 2014-11-30 05:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |
| 5678 | Carol | 2014-12-01 05:26:29.000000000 | 1001 |

[Oracle 11g fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NemdJyu3)

If you were using Oracle 12 or later then you can greatly simplify the solution by using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         sender_name,
         transaction_date,
         amount
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           sender_name,
           transaction_date,
           amount,
           SUM(amount) OVER (
             PARTITION BY sender_name, TRUNC(transaction_date)
           ) AS daily_amount
    FROM   transactions
  )
  WHERE  daily_amount > 1000
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY sender_name
  ORDER BY transaction_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (consecutive_days+ last_day)
  DEFINE
    consecutive_days AS NEXT(transaction_date) < TRUNC(transaction_date) + 2,
    last_day AS FIRST(TRUNC(transaction_date)) + 4 <= transaction_date
)
```

[Oracle 18 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BCVWnC2W)

Comment: Thanks a lot MT0. You know I use dbForge Studio for Oracle 11g. And when use the code it gives issue. The issue that IDE can’t understand those 3 sender_name  in each Select causes getting from unknown table. Did you get me?)

Comment: @MSS As shown by the fiddles linked in the answer, the code works in Oracle 11g. I do not use dbForge Studio and I "do not get you" as the answer uses valid Oracle syntax and works. If you are having trouble with your IDE then I suggest that you try a different IDE that supports the syntax that Oracle uses.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot @MT0. Let me try to use a different IDE

Comment: one more thing. For example if I have a lot of columns on `Transactions` should I write all of them on each `Select`?

Comment: @MSS You can give the table and each inline view an alias and then use `SELECT alias.*, other_columns FROM table_name alias` if you do not want to write them all out (but you only need to write them out once and then copy/paste for each nested sub-query).

Comment: does it give error on last `Order by` cause if I use `SELECT alias.*, other_columns FROM table_name alias`?

Comment: @MSS [No](https://dbfiddle.uk/a4icc1um)

Comment: sorry for disturbing, one more thing: if I put `daily_amount >1001` I dont get anything, while `summ` of `amount` column will be bigger than `1001` on `5 consecutive days` for `sender`

Comment: @MSS The answer checks for `> 1000` in each `transaction_date` day (which appears to be what the question is asking for). If you want to check if there is `> 1000` in a 5-day consecutive period then that appears to be something different to what is being asked in the question (and is an example of why your question should include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for sample data and the expected output which demonstrates the problem and gives examples of edge-cases like this).

Comment: I see, My English is no so perfect thats why I cant explain properly, sorry for that. So, If I want to check if there is > 1000 in a 5-day consecutive period what should we change in code?

Comment: I checked something by fiddles link you gave, I think its not counting by consecutive days but its counting by consecutive date and hours. In example when we give 5 consecutive days it must shown `Alice, Carol and Debry`. While its not getting `Debry`, because of not consecutive hours.

Comment: @MSS Debra is not returned because there is no transaction on 2014-11-29 so there are not 5 consecutive days.